# Heating a semiconductor device

Tags: semiconductor-physics

My book([this is my book, page $468$](http://ncert.nic.in/ncerts/l/leph206.pdf)) says this thing:

> No external heating is required by a semiconductor device

I'm confused. I know silicon conducts electricity when it is heated. So, why heating is not required? Is the case true in case of all semiconductor devices or a few one?

Comment: A semiconductor typically consists of "doped"-silicon, which in turn conducts electricity. Conductivity can be changed by different dopands and temperature, but heating is most commonly not required.
It think wiki-article is quite helpfull (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semiconductor).

Comment: Your book is comparing solid-state devices to vacuum tubes. Vacuum tubes require a high filament temperature to operate; solid-state devices (which lack a filament and operate by a different mechanism) do not and will happily work at room temperature. In fact, far from being a requirement, internal heating (which arises from the current pushing through the resistive semiconductor) is now considered an undesirable byproduct in high-density devices.

Comment: If you had quoted correctly -- *No external heating or large evacuated space
is required by the semiconductor devices* -- then it would have been obvious what was being discussed without even having to refer to your link.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This obviously refers to a basic advantage of semiconductor devices as compared to vacuum tubes which can be used for similar electronic purposes. Electronic vacuum tubes usually use electrons emitted from a heated cathode filament by thermionic emission. This requires substantial energy. Such a heating is not required in semiconductor devices.

Answer (score 0):

According to basic knowledge about semiconductors. 
At room temperature many carriers are excited from valence band to conduction (generation electron-hole pair by **thermal energy**) and that's why you don't need additional external heat. Of course additional heating will gave you more free electrons that can move freely when u apply an electic field.